# Convert structure large XML file To CSV without using tag names

Tags: python, csv, xml-parsing

Iam trying to convert large XML file to CSV format , Below is my code and sample file ,Sample file (part of xml file )

```
<PostalAddress>
    <Id>5464443597076195439</Id>
    <AddUserId>SYSTEM_USER</AddUserId>
    <AddDate>2013-01-05T18:08:42-06:00</AddDate>
    <LastPersistenceTransactionUserId>SYSTEM_USER</LastPersistenceTransactionUserId>
    <LastPersistenceTransactionDate>2013-07-11T08:21:34-05:00</LastPersistenceTransactionDate>
    <LastPersistenceTransactionType tc="2"/>
    <ExternalReferenceId>3200723</ExternalReferenceId>
    <SchemaVersion>2</SchemaVersion>
    <Type tc="1"/>
    <Usage tc="2"/>
    <Valid>true</Valid>
    <Overridable>true</Overridable>
    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
    <Line1>4849 RONSON CT</Line1>
    <Line2>STE 208</Line2>
    <City>SAN DIEGO</City>
    <State tc="6"/>
    <PostalCode>92111</PostalCode>
    <Country tc="1"/>
</PostalAddress>
```

Below is my code

```
import codecs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import sys
class gokul:

    def __init__(self, input_file, output_file, encoding='utf-8'):

        self.output_buffer = []
        self.output = None
       self.context = et.iterparse(input_file, from bs4 import BeautifulSoup=("start", "end"))
        try:
            self.output = codecs.open(output_file, "w", encoding=encoding)
        except:
            print("Failed to open the output file")
            raise


    def convert(self, tag="item", delimiter=",", ignore=[], noheader=False,
                limit=-1, buffer_size=1000):
        event, root = next(self.context)

        items = []
        header_line = []
        field_name = ''

        tagged = False
        started = False
        n = 0

        for event, elem in self.context:

            should_write = elem.tag != tag and started and elem.tag not in ignore
            should_tag = not tagged and should_write and not noheader
            i=0 

            if event == 'start':
                if elem.tag == tag and not started:
                    started = True
                elif should_tag:
                    field_name = '_'.join((field_name, elem.tag)) if field_name else elem.tag

            else:
                if should_write:
                    if should_tag:
                        header_line.append(field_name)  
                        field_name = field_name.rpartition('_' + elem.tag)[0]
                    items.append('' if elem.text is None else elem.text.strip().replace('"', r'""'))

                elif elem.tag == tag and len(items) > 0:

                    if header_line and not tagged:
                        self.output.write(delimiter.join(header_line) + '\n')
                    tagged = True
                    self.output_buffer.append(r'"' + (r'"' + delimiter + r'"').join(items) + r'"')
                    items = []
                    n += 1
                    if n == limit:
                        break
                    if len(self.output_buffer) > buffer_size:
                        self._write_buffer()

                elem.clear()  

        self._write_buffer()  
        self.output.close()

        return n
    def _write_buffer(self):
        """Write records from buffer to the output file"""

        self.output.write('\n'.join(self.output_buffer) + '\n')
        self.output_buffer = []

         converter = gokul(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], encoding="utf-8")
         converter.convert(tag=sys.argv[3])
```

Comment: what problem are you having? Why does the code you posted not work correctly?

Comment: @FoamyGuy , I m trying to convert the large xml file to csv , but in above code we need to pass tag name has 3rd argument and in this code tag having attribute it's value not populating in csv file.i want to resolve these two issues , can u plz help me on this